# Laravel @ Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to understand, why I'm not able to popup users balance using paypal sandox.

Here is my AccountBalance.php part code, when user paid in paypal

```
public function rebuildBalance($user_id, $amount, $bonus = 0, $frozen = false, $currency) {
        $balance = UserBalance::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('currency_id', $currency)->first();

        if ($bonus == 0) {
            if ($frozen) {
                $balance->balance_frozen += $amount;
            } else {

                $balance->balance += $amount;
            }

        } else {
            $balance->bonus += $amount;
        }
```

And when transaction is over, I got Creating default object from empty value

to this part `$balance->balance += $amount;`

Thankx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `$balance` variable is `null` from this query:

```
 $balance = UserBalance::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('currency_id', $currency)->first();
```

Figure out why this query doesn't work the way you intend it to and you should be fine. A good start would be to figure out what `$currency` variable holds - and make sure you pass it correctly when calling `rebuildBalance(args)`.

If you try to assign a property to `null` you get your exact error.

Comment: in db I have record for this transaction, and I wondering... why there currency_id is equal 2, if table `currency` has only 1 value euro with ID 1